# Using strmatch in a loop

Tags: matlab

Can I do the something below coded using or without  loop?

Actually I am having a character array comprising of unique words more than `5000` and other array comprising of approx `3000` words. I want to search each word in my array named as word in other array named as `uniques` and wish to create a feature vector i.e. values `1` if exists and `0` if doesn't.

I am doing the following..

```
load 'uniques'  %uniques={'alpha','ok',abc'};
fid=fopen(myfilename);
words=textscan(fid,'%s');
fclose(fid);
word=words{1,1}; %word={'good','bad',anywhere','countries','ok',done','abc'}

for i=1:size(uniques,2)
ind=strmatch(word(i), uniques, 'exact');
end
```

Now, seeing above as examples before `uniques` and `word` arays, my system must return `0` for `good` as `good` is not there in `uniques` and same `0` values but `1` for `ok` because it does exist in `uniques`. All in all, I must have in the end, `{0,0,0,0,1,0,1}`  ..

After I run, it gives me `ind=[]`

Please guide

Comment: In its current form, your question is difficult to understand and not likely to get an answer. But luckily you can improve it as SO allows you to edit your question! Please **provide example data** of each of your arrays (but use say 5 elements instead of 5000 and 3 instead of 3000) **and also include a hand worked example output**. When you add the sample inputs, please use matlab syntax so we can just copy and paste into matlab.

Comment: You are overwriting `ind` at each stage in your loop. In addition, why you are taking the size of `uniques` as your loop size and then indexing into `word` is a mystery to me.

Comment: can either `uniques` or `word` have duplicated words or are they both unique lists?

Comment: No @Dan uniques array has uniques but yes other one may have repetitions its a scattered array i.e. word array having all characters that may or may not be unique

Comment: @MazharIqbalRana the `ismember` function should solve this for you

Comment: @Dan Thanks but how will I write it under loop? will it be like :

ind = ismember(word(i),uniques);

Comment: You don't need a loop anymore, `ismember` will do it all in one shot

Comment: @nkjt yes I am traversing through 2nd dimension of uniques so did it...

Comment: No, you do `word(i)` but just `uniques` in the loop so you're not traversing through `uniques` at all and if `size(uniques,2)` is not the same size as `word` you are either ignoring some of the content of `word` or you will get an error. Dan has given you some useful advice so you can avoid the loop but it will benefit you to also understand why your original loop was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have described the exact functionality of the [`ismember`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) function:

```
ismember(word, uniques);
```

as an aside, this is what @nkjt was saying about fixing your loop:

```
for i=1:size(word,2)
    ind(i)=strmatch(word(i), uniques, 'exact');
end
```

But this loop is unnecessary since Matlab has this as a built in function